# Simple Htaccess question

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?abc=xyz(&(app=([a-z]+))) #i don't know it is right or wrong

########LOGIN########
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156&rp=([a-zA-Z0-9=]+)
RewriteRule ^events/login.php$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/login.php?rp=%1 [R=301,L]

########SEARCH########SEARCH########################
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?search=([a-z]+)&event_id=156&submit=Search
RewriteRule ^is2011/([a-z]+).php$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/$1.php?search=%1 [R=301,L]
```

I just want to skip above rewrite rules if and only if there is app=xyz in query string.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi Biggs, I have edited the question. Please check the same. I just want to skip some rewrite rules for a particular condtion. condition is whenever browser found app=xyz in the address bar. It just skips the rewrite rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if the following conditions are met, SKIP the rewriteRules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?abc=xyz(&(app=([a-z]+))) #i don't know it is right or wrong
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [skip=2]

########LOGIN########
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?event_id=156&rp=([a-zA-Z0-9=]+)
RewriteRule ^events/login.php$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/login.php?rp=%1 [R=301,L]

########SEARCH########SEARCH########################
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?search=([a-z]+)&event_id=156&submit=Search
RewriteRule ^is2011/([a-z]+).php$ http://www.xyz.com/is2011/$1.php?search=%1 [R=301,L]
```

The rewrite rule i added does not make any substitution in the query string matched by its RewriteCond. The skip flag skips the next *num* rules, in this case two. See RewriteRule's directive documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule.